# Как создать массив такого вида?

Tags: php

Вывожу нужные мне записи из базы:

```
$db = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `deal` WHERE DATE(date_open) BETWEEN '2018-07-10' AND '".date('Y-m-d')."'");
if ($db) while ($deal = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo $deal['date_open'];
}
```

Получаю такой список:

```
2018-07-13
2018-07-13
2018-07-15
2018-07-15
2018-07-19
2018-07-19
2018-07-19
```

Мне нужно объединить их по дате. Хочу получить такой массив:

```
0 - [1], [2]
1 - [3], [4]
и так далее
```

где 1 2 3 4 это id записи ( **$deal['id']** )

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$deal = array(
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-13', 'id' => 1],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-13', 'id' => 2],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-15', 'id' => 3],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-15', 'id' => 4],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-19', 'id' => 5],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-19', 'id' => 6],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-19', 'id' => 7]
);

$result = array();
foreach ($deal as $value) {
    $result[$value['date_open']][] = $value['id'];
}
$result = array_map(function($v) { return '[' . implode('], [', $v) . ']'; }, $result);
var_dump(array_values($result));
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> "[1], [2]"
  [1]=> "[3], [4]"
  [2]=> "[5], [6], [7]"
}
```

Comment: а как создать такой массив $deal  ?

Comment: `while ($deal = $db->fetch_assoc()) {` - он по идеи у вас таким форматом и должен быть

Comment: мне нужно его создать в этом цикле, потому что там сейчас еще поля выводятся которые мне не нужны, и на выходе я изменяю некоторые данные

Comment: @Денис я не понимаю что вы хотите. Вы написали: `echo $deal['date_open'];` и получаете список дат, потом вы сказали что у вас есть `$deal['id']`, отсюда можно сделать вывод, что все необходимые данные в `$deal` уже имеются, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Денис Я вас понял, вам просто нужно использовать `$deal = $db->fetch_all()` документация: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php . ЛИБО как костыль, в цикле `while` формировать этот массив `$deal_array = array('date_open' => $deal['date_open'], 'id' => $deal['id']);`, тогда ПОСЛЕ цикла вы получите массив

Answer (score 2):

> Мне нужно объединить их по дате.

Вот так можно объединить не теряя, самих дат:

```
$array = array(
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-13', 'id' => 1],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-13', 'id' => 2],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-15', 'id' => 3],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-15', 'id' => 4],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-19', 'id' => 5],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-19', 'id' => 6],
    ['date_open' => '2018-07-19', 'id' => 7]
);

$res = [];

foreach($array as $k => $d){
    $res[$d['date_open']][] = $d['id'];
}
print_r($res);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [2018-07-13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2018-07-15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2018-07-19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

)
```